# Error when accessing array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to access the `$_GET` array in PHP like so:

```
<?php

$incl = $_GET("incl");

if ( $incl == "" ) { $incl = "home"; }
```

Whenever I access the script, I get a 500 error. Any idea why?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. `(` and `)` are not the same as `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1):

If you get an unexpected HTTP 500 error that you haven't sent yourself from PHP, this means there's an actual error in your script.

In this case, your problem is this line:

```
$incl = $_GET("incl");
```

`$_GET` is an array, so when you want to access values within it by key, you need to do so with `[]`, not `()`:

```
$incl = $_GET['incl'];
```

Further, your check for `$incl` being empty should look like this:

```
if(empty($_GET['incl']){
  $incl = 'home';
} else {
  $incl = $_GET['incl'];
}
```